# How can I pass a RDD from scala to python?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to pass a Spark RDD from Scala to Python so that I can then call functions on it from PySpark.

My scala code returns
`rdd.toJavaRDD()`, which I then read in python via:

```
scala_res = sc._jvm.com.package.Class.method()
from pyspark.rdd import RDD
python_rdd = RDD(scala_res, sc._sc)
```

This initially appears to work, but if I call functions on this RDD, like `python_rdd.count()`, it will start a Spark job to get the result but error out with the error: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unexpected element type class java.lang.Long`.

It seems maybe I'm missing some conversion step from java to python RDD?

I'm using Scala 2.11, and Spark 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some gateway from JVM generated code to Python like `Py4J` gateway:

- Build a jar file with a code that yields your RDD.
- Include this jar file to classpath w\ `--driver-class-path` for `spark-shell` or `spark-submit`
- Instantiate a JVM instance and reuse necessary Scala code:

```
jvm = sc._jvm
rdd_result = jvm.foo.Bar.baz()
```

Comment: Hm this appears to be exactly what I've done (edited question to make this more clear). This actually mostly works too except that I can't call any functions that invoke a real spark job.


Any ideas why I'd get the above error?

Comment: @RyanCheu Maybe I misunderstood the question, if you want just to get the result of Scala RDD - the code above works fine (I've just updated it). If you want to pass the the method that yields RDD itself you have to use some serialisation like `PickleSerializer`